# Cant Get C# Form To Change Red

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, tao-framework

So I am following the book "C# Game Programming - For Serious Game Creation" and I'm at a part in the book that has you create OpenGL form with Tao and change the color from black to red.
Here is my code which is exactly the same as in the book

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tao.OpenGl;

namespace GameLoop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FastLoop _fastLoop;
        bool _fullscreen = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            _fastLoop = new FastLoop(GameLoop);
            InitializeComponent();
            _openGLControl.InitializeContexts();
            if (_fullscreen)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
        void GameLoop(double elapsedTime)
        {
            Gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            Gl.glFinish();
            _openGLControl.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors at all, it just simply stays black. What are the possible reasons for why this could be happening?

code for other game loop

```
static void GameLoop(double elapsedTime)
{
    // GameCode goes here
    // GetInput
    // Process
    // Render
    System.Console.WriteLine("Loop");
}
```

Comment: Does your `GameLoop` method get executed?

Comment: yes it should I have another class that runs the game loop method and it says Loop over and over in the console and its almost the same code I added it into the main question

Comment: try using Gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);in constructor public Form1(), i think this will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Ali Kazmi and Matthew I figured it out. by puting the code into public Form1() It worked and I was able to conclude that the method was not updating and Im very new to C# I think it was because the other game loop was not letting it get that far. I removed it and it all works fine.